# Condition to get value in XML and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml

```
<out>   
  <settings>
    <setting name="address1" addr="test1"/>
    <setting name="address2" addr="test2"/>
    <setting name="address3" addr="test3"/>
    <setting name="address4" addr="test4"/>
  </settings>
</out>
```

I want to get value if condition for name attribute match with corresponding value
for example: Get test3 if condition is name="address3"

something like below which gives me result test1 and that is wrong

```
 <xsl:if test="/out/settings/setting/@name='address3'">
        <xsl:value-of select="/out/settings/setting/@addr"/>
 </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:if test="/out/settings/setting/@name='address3'">
```

is true if *any* of the `setting` elements have the name `address3`.

```
<xsl:value-of select="/out/settings/setting/@addr"/>
```

will output the value of the `@addr` attribute on the first `setting` in document order (XSLT 1.0) or the concatenation of all of them (XSLT 2.0).  If you want the `value-of` specifically the "address3" setting then just do

```
<xsl:value-of select="/out/settings/setting[@name='address3']/@addr"/>
```

There's no need for the `if` check because when there's no "address3" `setting` the `select` will give you an empty node set or sequence, and the `value-of` an empty set is the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without the conditional by using a predicate in the path expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/out/settings/setting[@name='address3']/@addr"/>
```

Or, if you prefer the conditional expression, you can use this:

```
<xsl:template match="/out/settings/setting">
  <xsl:if test="@name='address3'">
    <xsl:value-of select="@addr"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```